# what is this urls that are changed when we click them

Tags: facebook, url, web

On facebook, I see pages, posts urls like this one

http://econ.st/1dQAfN2

when you click it (or copy and pasts it manually) it changes to the **actual** link which is http://www.economist.com/blogs/graphicdetail/2014/04/daily-chart-1?fsrc=scn/fb/wl/dc/putinspipelines

what is the first link please? why clicking it makes it changes to the second link? **it is not redictring** i guess.

I see these links a lot on facebook and social networks.

Thanks

Comment: why do you guess its not redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

The page responds with a

< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301, 
see 1)

Your browser then follows to http://econ.trib.al/QKMTguP, see 2)

Whence to http://econ.st/1jF8V4a

Whence to http://econ.trib.al/wvPqtzG, see 3)

Whence to http://www.economist.com/blogs/graphicdetail/2014/04/daily-chart-1?fsrc=scn/fb/wl/dc/putinspipelines

1)

```
   $ curl -v http://econ.st/1dQAfN2
    * Adding handle: conn: 0x5d7e80
    * Adding handle: send: 0
    * Adding handle: recv: 0
    * Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
    * - Conn 0 (0x5d7e80) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
    * About to connect() to econ.st port 80 (#0)
    *   Trying 69.58.188.49...
    * Connected to econ.st (69.58.188.49) port 80 (#0)
    > GET /1dQAfN2 HTTP/1.1
    > User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
    > Host: econ.st
    > Accept: */*
    >
    < HTTP/1.1 301 Moved
    * Server nginx is not blacklisted
    < Server: nginx
    < Date: Fri, 04 Apr 2014 11:53:21 GMT
    < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    < Connection: keep-alive
    < Set-Cookie: _bit=533e9d31-00126-02167-2e1cf10a;domain=.econ.st;expires=Wed Oct  1 11:53:21 2014;path=/; HttpOnly
    < Cache-control: private; max-age=90
    < Location: http://econ.trib.al/QKMTguP
    < MIME-Version: 1.0
    < Content-Length: 119
    <
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>bit.ly</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="http://econ.trib.al/QKMTguP">moved here</a>
    </body>
    </html>* Connection #0 to host econ.st left intact
```

2)

```
$ curl -v http://econ.trib.al/QKMTguP
* Adding handle: conn: 0x5a7e80
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x5a7e80) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to econ.trib.al port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 23.21.170.236...
* Connected to econ.trib.al (23.21.170.236) port 80 (#0)
> GET /QKMTguP HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: econ.trib.al
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Date: Fri, 04 Apr 2014 11:56:24 GMT
< Location: http://econ.st/1jF8V4a
* Server nginx/1.4.4 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.4.4
< Set-Cookie: tribal="nbo2cJBTQpi9R/Q0VJmy/g=="; expires=Fri, 06 Jan 2034 23:13:40 GMT; Path=/; Version=2
< Content-Length: 99
< Connection: keep-alive
<
This resource has permanently moved to <a href='http://econ.st/1jF8V4a'>http://econ.st/1jF8V4a</a>.* Connection #0 to host econ.trib.al left intact
```

3)

```
    $ curl -v http://econ.trib.al/wvPqtzG
* Adding handle: conn: 0x4a7e80
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x4a7e80) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to econ.trib.al port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 107.22.241.165...
* Connected to econ.trib.al (107.22.241.165) port 80 (#0)
> GET /wvPqtzG HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: econ.trib.al
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Date: Fri, 04 Apr 2014 11:59:01 GMT
< Location: http://www.economist.com/blogs/graphicdetail/2014/04/daily-chart-1?fsrc=scn/fb/wl/dc/putinspipelines
* Server nginx/1.4.4 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.4.4
< Set-Cookie: tribal="6/+hHfDfTpaX5C0U/Kl8dA=="; expires=Fri, 06 Jan 2034 23:13:40 GMT; Path=/; Version=2
< Content-Length: 255
< Connection: keep-alive
<
This resource has permanently moved to <a href='http://www.economist.com/blogs/graphicdetail/2014/04/daily-chart-1?fsrc=scn/fb/wl/dc/putinspipelines'>http://www
.economist.com/blogs/graphicdetail/2014/04/daily-chart-1?fsrc=scn/fb/wl/dc/putinspipelines</a>.* Connection #0 to host econ.trib.al left intact
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a shortened url. [econ.st](http://econ.st) is registered by the The Economist Newspaper. The change that you actually see is just a redirect to the long url.

Google, for example, has something very similar http://goo.gl.

You can read more about it on the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening) page.